# How to show hook output in Tortoise Hg log window?

Tags: mercurial, hook, tortoisehg, mercurial-hook

I need simple hook for mercurial that checks commit comment using pattern. Here is my hook:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# save as .hg/check_whitespace.py and make executable

import re

def check_comment(comment):
    #
    print 'Checking comment...'
    pattern = '^((Issue \d+:)|(No Issue:)).+'
    if re.match(pattern, comment, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        return 1
    else:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Comment does not match pattern. You must start it with "Issue 12323:" or "No Issue:"'
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os, sys
    comment=os.popen('hg tip --template "{desc}"').read()
    if not check_comment(comment):
        sys.exit(1)
sys.exit(0)
```

It works. It even shows error message `'Comment does not match pattern. You must start it with "Issue 12323:" or "No Issue:"'` when I commit from console. But when I trying to commit from Tortoise Hg Workbench, only system message is shown: `abort: pretxncommit.check_comment hook exited with status 1`.

I need to inform user what is wrong. Is there any way to force Tortoise Hg to show output from hook?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried writing to sys.out instead of sys.err?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work by making it an **in-process hook** rather than an external hook. In-process [hooks](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) are defined quite differently, however.

First, the python file needs only a single function that will be called by the name in the hook definition. The hook function is passed `ui`, `repo`, and `hooktype` objects. It is also passed additional objects based on the type of hook. For `pretrxncommit`, it is passed `node`, `parent1`, and `parent2`, but you're only interested in node, so the rest are gathered in `kwargs`. The `ui` object is used to give the status and error messages.

Contents of `check_comment.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

def check_comment(ui, repo, hooktype, node=None, **kwargs):
    ui.status('Checking comment...\n')
    comment = repo[node].description()
    pattern = '^((Issue \d+:)|(No Issue:)).+'
    if not re.match(pattern, comment, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        ui.warn('Comment does not match pattern. You must start it with "Issue 12323:" or "No Issue:"\n')
        return True
```

In the `hgrc`, the hook would be defined with `python:/path/to/file.py:function_name`, like this:

```
[hooks]
pretxncommit.check_comment = python:/path/to/check_comment.py:check_comment
```

The `.suffix_name` on `pretxncommit` is to avoid overriding any globally defined hook, especially if this is defined in the repository's `hgrc` rather than the global one. Suffixes are how one allows multiple responses to the same hook.

Answer (score 0):

In case the hook runs on a repository that is served via e.g. hgserve:
I use this small Python function in a `pretxnchangegroup` script to show the same output

- in the server log
- in the TortoiseHg workbench Log pan or the cmd line

:

```
def log(ui, string):
    print(string) # will show up as "remote:" on the client
    ui.status("{0}\n".format(string)) # will show up in the same hg process: hgserve ; append newline
    return
```